# Is the integral of $\exp(t^s)$ in $O(h^{1-s}\exp(h^s))$?

Tags: integration, inequality

For $h>0$ and $s\in(0,2)$ I want to prove that $\int_0^h e^{t^s} dt=O(h^{1-s}\exp(h^s))$. The case $s=1$ is trivial.

For $s<1$, I have

\begin{align}
\int_0^h e^{t^s} dt&=\int_0^h t^{1-s} t^{s-1}e^{t^s} dt\\
&\le h^{1-s} \int_0^h  t^{s-1}e^{t^s} dt\\
&=Ch^{1-s} \exp(h^s)
\end{align}

If $s>1$, I can't use the same argument for the bound. Is the bound still true?

If its not true, is it possible to prove $\int_0^h e^{t^s} dt=O(h^2\exp(h^s))$?

Comment: Does $O(h^2 \exp(h^s))$ denote the behavior of the integral as $h \searrow 0$ or $h \to +\infty$? Presumably the latter.

Comment: yes the latter, thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)
$$
\displaystyle \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to  + \infty } \cfrac{{\displaystyle \int_0^h {{\rm e}^{t^s } {\rm d}t} }}{{\displaystyle \frac{1}{s}h^{1 - s}\, {\rm e}^{h^s } }} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to  + \infty } \frac{s}{{(1 - s)h^{ - s}  + s}} = 1,
$$
for any $s>0$. Therefore, we even have the stronger result that
$$
\int_0^h {{\rm e}^{t^s } {\rm d}t} \sim \frac{1}{s}h^{1 - s}\, {\rm e}^{h^s },
$$
as $h\to+\infty$, for any fixed $s>0$.

Another approach is to perform the change of variables from $t$ to $w$ via $t^s  = h^s (1 - w)$ and use [Watson's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson%27s_lemma):
$$
\int_0^h {{\rm e}^{t^s } {\rm d}t}  = \frac{1}{s}h\,{\rm e}^{h^s } \int_0^1 {{\rm e}^{ - h^s w} (1 - w)^{1/s - 1} {\rm d}w}  \sim \frac{1}{s}h^{1 - s} \,{\rm e}^{h^s }\! \left( {1 + \frac{{s - 1}}{s}\frac{1}{{h^s }} +  \ldots } \right),
$$
as $h\to+\infty$, for any fixed $s>0$.